# what is the reason for assigning strings in this way?

Tags: android, string

I have seen some code to read/write sms in android applications.Everywhere i see strings like

```
colName =  colName + " so and so";
```

what is the difference if i use

```
colName = "hello";
```

Comment: Did you mean to write += in the second example?

Comment: @user1870724 see my answer. I tried to make it clear

Answer (score 2):

Difference is following:
If you use `colName =  colName + " so and so";` then you **append** something to the colName

if you use `colName = "hello";` you just **set** colName to be "hello"

So if you run

```
colName = "hello";
colName = "hello";
```

The resulting String will be "hello"

If you use

```
colName = "hello";
colName =  colName + " so and so";
```

The resulting String will be "hello so and so"

Answer (score 2):

in (`colName =  colName + " so and so";`) this is a concatenation..
ex : if `colName = "hello"` after `colName =  colName + " so and so";` it will be `"hello so and so"`

in `colName = "hello";` you are only asignning value to `colName`..

Answer (score 1):

colName =  colName + " so and so"; is a concatenation. You are appending the string "so and so" to colName .Suppose you have this:

```
colName = "I told you";
colName = colNanme + " so and so"; // resulting string = I told you so and so
```

Another way to write it:

```
colName = "I told you";
colName += "so and so"; // resulting string = I told you so and so
```

Whereas for colName = "I told you"; you are just assigning a value to the variable colName.

```
colName = "I told you";
colName = "so and so"; // resulting string = so and so
```

Hope its clear